# Screen tearing for minor screen updates

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, resolution, tearing

This is an issue which I am facing after a run into EDID issues from my monitor.

In a system where everything was working perfectly fine, one day, I boot up to get a low resolution display on my Ubuntu machine. After some debugging on Xorg.log and some restarts, I found out the monitor had stopped sending its EDID to the system.

Fortunately, I found that my Windows setup had my edid values cached in its registry, copied the binary values and formed the edid.bin that the NVIDIA driver needed. After manually putting together xorg.conf with the custom edid.bin specified in it, I got back to my native resolution. Presently, the system shows no problems in display resolution, however, whenever there are very minute changes to the frame (like moving the test cursor in a document), I spot tearing on the screen (with two cursors instead of one!!).

Can anyone help me out on this?

Auxiliary info:

1. I never make updates on my machine - drivers or software
2. Operating system : Ubuntu 12.04 (no updates since the install)
3. I am using the NVIDIA proprietary drivers downloaded from the official webpage (not changed this since 2 years)
4. Monitor model : Samsung SyncMaster SA300
5. Card : NVIDIA Fermi GTX470

Thanks

L

Comment: <<<-- BUMP -->>>

Comment: why do you never make updates ?? 12.04 is LTS that have 5 years of support. your machine is full of security holes...

Comment: Considering that my usage of the machine does not need me to install any new softwares and I have no qualms on reinstalling the OS, I do not need security updates.

Comment: Does this also happen in the guest session?

Comment: yes - it happens in the guest session as well

Answer (score 1):

There is a serious issue with the kernel vs the nvidia driver (https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1401792)

In my experience so far with 14.04, I've found that setting any value for 'underscanning' in the nvidia control panel will make this issue go away until the next time you reboot.

However, it must be done every time you reboot.  I've found no answers on here; I've tried all of the nvidia drivers, including the xorg-edgers drivers, but so far no joy.

The bug report I mentioned is one of dozens of duplicates that all point to an incompatibility between the kernel and the nvidia driver, and for over a year (at least on that one specific bug report) the issue has yet to be correctly identified as either a kernel issue or an nvidia problem, let alone resolved.

My mobo/gpu hardware setup had been working fine for 2-3 years without issue until I installed 14.04, so I'm leaning toward a 14.04 issue... but that has not been confirmed by the people monitoring the bug reports.

**edit:**  sorry - I just saw that yours is 12.04, not 14.04.

Comment: I do not think the problem is with the driver - this was working just fine till just the day when I had to work around for the problem with edid as I mentioned - no driver changes have been made even after that.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late - but I found the problem:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/729908/-gt-334-21-redrawing-problems-in-gnome-3-10-3-12-gtx-580/

The issue was occurring only on gnome-shell. Unity ran fine in the meanwhile.

I have not got the patience to go through the whole thread and get the actual fix for it - shifting to KDE for now.

Leaving this question unanswered - if anyone does go through that conversation in the link above, please do respond with the actual fix: I will accept it and close this question.